# How to get log of running cron job

Tags: crontab

How can I tail the running cron job, so that I can come to the conclusion that my job is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the PID of your job:

```
ps ax | grep jobname
```

After that you can check if your job is working, by tracing its actions with `strace`.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you could echo something like `echo 'My job started on: ' $(date)` and in your cron, redirect both the stdout and the stderr to a file:

```
* * * * * /path/to/your/job &>/tmp/MyJobLog
```

If you want to check 'live' what your job is doing, just do `tail -f /tmp/MyJobLog`

Another option is to log the start (or the end) of your script in syslog with the `logger` command if supported by your distro.

Comment: Here the /path/to/your/job  means the location of the cron file or the location of the script which I enter in the cron file??

Comment: This is the path to your script. It is highly recommended to always specify full path to all scripts and commands in the cron file as it usually has no value for the `PATH` environment variable unless specifically set in the cron file.